# addChild is not a function error in dynatree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented addChild function in my code. but it gives me error of addChild is not a function. I have included all the related js and css files. but this function does not work.

here is my code.

```
function addNode(currentNode){                              

                 var childNode = currentNode.addChild({
              title: "My new node",
                  tooltip: "This folder and all child nodes were added programmatically."                   
             });

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code of your `addChild` function ?

Comment: Hi fiddler, I have already added the code. currentNode value contains the node i have selected. but i got error in second line where i am adding addChild.

Comment: The function you shared is `addNode`, not `addChild`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

```
    Using id of my dynatree i solved it. I was mistakenly using id of my div tag.
```